how localize authentication pages with api, when I have install breeze auth packege?using laravel11
Http\Middleware\SetAppLang.php
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (! in_array($request->segments(1), config('app.available_locales'))) {

            abort(404);
        }

        App::setLocale($request->segments(1));
        return $next($request);

    }

routes\auth.php
Route::middleware(['guest','languages'])->prefix('{locale}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('login');
.
.
.
});

config\app.php
 'available_locales' => [
        'en',
        'ar'
    ],

I tried to translate the web application but the URL did not work.
can you help what's the problem?

Can you please explain what is this routes\auth.php ?

I have this route page when install breeze packge, and all the auth route in this page.
